# Spring boot 2.1 and Hibernate 5.3 SessionFactory not Autowired when annotating the Dao classes with @Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I am auto wiring  hibernate session factory in a Dao implementation annotated with @Repository spring annotation it fails to create the SessionFactory and Dao bean but, it works without the @Repository annotation.

I search through lot of questions and answers but all are related to the earlier version of hibernate and spring boot like unwrap and create a session factory bean but all those methods are not compatible with spring-boot 2.1 and the latest Hibernate version.

are there any specific method to create and autowired a hibernate session factory in spring boot 2.1 and latest hibernate versions(5.3)?

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) {
        Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(user);
    }


}
```

in the above code SessionFactory auto-wired without @Repository and I create a config class with a bean as below

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(@Autowired EntityManagerFactory factory) {
            if (factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
            }
            return factory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

}
```

It course "The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:" error

Comment: Why do you use the `SessionFactory`, I suggest to change to `EntityManager` and using `persist instead. The error is coming from the fact that as of Hibernate 5.2 the `SessionFactory` extends `EntityManagerFactory`. This disables the Spring bOot auto configuration of the `EntityManagerFactory` and now you have a dependency from the `SessionFactory` to the `SessionFactory` because that is an `EntityManagerFactory` as well.

Comment: you can also unwrap `SessionFactory` from `EntityManager`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
    sessionBuilder.scanPackages("com.your.domain.package");
    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setMinimumIdle(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.minimumIdle")));
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize")));
    config.setIdleTimeout(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.idleTimeout")));
    config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    config.setDataSourceClassName(env.getProperty("spring.datasource.className"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("url", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}
```

@Mr. Decent , change your configuration this way in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Why we use this explicit hikari configuration, spring boot 2.x comes with hikari as the default datasource implementation and we have nothing to do if we want to use Hikari in an application based on Spring Boot 2.x

Comment: Its not mandatory, you may or may not use in order to configure.

Comment: Why the Spring-boot auto configuration not auto-wired the auto configured default datasource(hikari) and create this and the above configuration breaks the JPA EntityManagerFactory too.

Comment: @Mr.Decent if you want to acheive this , just Autowire EntirtyManager in your Repository class.

Comment: You don't need the `DataSource` configuration, Spring Boot will configure one for you. The `SessionFactory` is the `EntityManagerFactory` so it is interchangeable as of Hibernate 5.3. Nonetheless I suggest you use `EntityManager` instead of `SessionFactory` with a `Session` as there hardly is a need to do that nowadays with the current state of JPA.

Comment: @M. Deinum, If I use EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory how can I use SessionFactory and Session aware features and how about the thread related issues if we unwrap the session using EntityManager. Is the unwrap(Session.class) is equal to getCurrentSession() or openSession() in the SessionFactory object?

Comment: The `EntityManager` is the `Session` (and vice-versa). Also what session aware features do you need?